# Need a help with Java JTables and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Currently I am working on a Java Swing Project and I have a jTable in my UI. It works like an Excel Sheet where user can edit multiple columns and multiple rows. After edited there's a button for save the data into the database. I was googling to get a code for how to do it. But still couldn't find a proper one.

Does anyone have come up with same kinda problem and found a solution or is there anyone to tell me how to do it. Code help is preferable.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to read the [JDBC Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) first.

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you know how to add an ActionListener to a button? Do you know how to get the data out of the JTable by using the getValueAt(...) method? Do you know how to create the SQL statement to update the database table? Put those 3 steps together and you has a solution.

Comment: Actually I know how to add to db but I dont know is how to retrieve multiple column and rows which were edited to send to the db

Answer (score 0):

You may do it in 2 ways:

1. Iterate (using loops) through the database and get each value (using `getValueAt()` method) and assign them to variables. Then add them to the database in the normal way.
2. Or you can create an object from the database and save it in a MySQL `BLOB`.

I think the 2nd method is easier and more efficient. For how to do it, try googling for MySQL BLOBs.

Comment: but this will be an issue when retrieving the data and update it right? first method will be work, but yeah its not an efficient way to do it when it comes to around 5 columns and 10 rows table right :)

Comment: Yes, the first method will be hard on memory then. But in the second method you can create a modal class to assign your table and provide setter/getter methods _in that_ class. So you when retrieving data, you can just cast it to an object of that class and do the manipulation work using that methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually keep track of the rows that have changed. You can use the [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) to help you with this. You will be notified every time a value has changed.

Then you will need to track the row containing the change maybe by keeping the row number in a Set. Then when the "Save" button is clicked, you can iterate throught the Set to get the rows and for each row you get the data for any column that is editable and then updated your database one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I could come up the solution. This is how I did it.

```
defaultGrnTbl = (DefaultTableModel) Dashboard.grnTbl.getModel();
            int columns = Dashboard.grnTbl.getColumnCount();
            int rows = Dashboard.grnTbl.getRowCount();
            String rowData = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                    rowData += Dashboard.grnTbl.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + ",";
                }
                saveGrnItem(rowData, rows, grnRecievedMark);
                rowData = "";
            }
```

Thanks